# Setting minimum benchmark in variable to increase mean to a certain level

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm following an Econometrics course in which we use R.
I'm a bit confused about the use of the while-loop for an exercise.
The situation is as follows:
I have a variable 'profit_loss' with a length of 10,000. The variable gives an overview of the financial performance of a company with its profits (positive values) and losses (negative values). From this I have to create another variable for which I have to create a minimum benchmark such that the mean of this variable becomes 20% higher than the mean of the original variable. In other words, I have to cut the losses to a certain point, which will increase the mean to a level where it's 20% higher than the original mean.
I was thinking of using a while-loop but while I can run some easy loops with this, I can't seem to figure out this one.
Any suggestions?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to [make your problem reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: set.seed(384);    
V1 = runif(10000,min=2,max=10);    
V2= rnorm(10000,mean=0,sd=2.04);    
V3= -0.5*rchisq(10000,3);     
profit_loss = V1+V2+V3;